# How to produce a column of weighted data using ave()

Tags: r

I recently asked a question about producing a column of weighted data using three years values in R. I was given the below code using the ave() function which worked perfectly.

```
data$smoothingOO <- 
  ave(x = data$OO_EST,
    data$Area_Code, # grouping 
    FUN = \(x) {
      # first row 
      y1 <- x[1L] * .75 + x[2L] * .25 
      # last row
      yl <- x[length(x)] * .75 + x[length(x) - 1L] * .25 
      # "inner rows" 
      y <- x * .5 + .25 * c(0L, x[-length(x)]) + .25 * c(x[-1L], 0)
      # combine first, inner minus first and last, and last row
      c(y1, y[-c(1L, length(y))], yl)
      })
```

The "inner rows" formula was based on the equation .5 * the current year + .25 * the previous year + .25 *the following year from the below data frame:

```
Year_Code Area_Code   Area_ItemName_ENG OO_EST
1     201112       512  Isle of Anglesey     2000
2     201213       512  Isle of Anglesey     2500
3     201314       512  Isle of Anglesey     2200
4     201415       512  Isle of Anglesey     2400
5     201516       512  Isle of Anglesey     2250
6     201617       512  Isle of Anglesey     2300
7     201718       512  Isle of Anglesey     2700
8     201819       512  Isle of Anglesey     2550
9     201920       512  Isle of Anglesey     2100
10    202021       512  Isle of Anglesey     2350
```

I am now looking to edit the "inner rows" formula to produce an output column of .25 * current year + .5 * previous year + .25 * (previous previous year). For example, for the 202021 row, I need .25 * 2350 + .5 * 2100 + .25 * 2550.

I have tried a number of variations such as

```
y <- x * .25 + .5 * c(0L, x[-length(x)]) + .25 * c(0L, x[-length(x - 1L)])
y <- x * .25 + .5 * c(0L, x[-length(x)]) + .25 * c(0L, x[-length(x) - 1L ])
y <- x * .25 + .5 * c(0L, x[-length(x)]) + .25 * c(1L, x[-length(x)])
y <- x * .25 + .5 * c(0L, x[-length(x)]) + .25 * c(0L, x[-length(2x)])
```

**Data**

Modiefied, from previous question.

```r
data <- 
  structure(list(
    Year_Code = c(201112, 201213, 201314, 201415, 201516, 
                  201617, 201718, 201819, 201920, 202021, 
                  201112, 201213, 201314, 201415, 201516), 
    Area_Code = c(512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 
                  512, 512, 333, 333, 333, 333, 333), 
    Area_ItemName_ENG = c(" Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  "), 
    OO_EST = c(2000, 2500, 2200, 2400, 2250, 2300, 2700, 2550, 
               2100, 2350, 2000, 2500, 2200, 2400, 2250)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

None of these have worked and it is because I do not fully understand what that specific line of the code is doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What should be done with the first two values? The first observation has no previous value; the second observation just one.

Comment: When copying code from another post a link to that post should be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same format as the previous answer, you could try

```
data$smoothingOO <- 
  ave(x = data$OO_EST,
      data$Area_Code, # grouping 
      FUN = \(x) {
        # first row 
        y1 <- x[1L] 
        # second row
        y2 <- x[1L] * .75 + x[2L] * .25 
        # "everything else" 
        y <- x * .25 + .5 * c(x[-1L], 0) + .25 * c(x[-c(1L,2L)], 0, 0)
        # combine first, second, and the remaining rows
        c(y1,y2,y[-c(length(x)-1,length(x)])
      })
```